# Using the identity theorem to prove existence of non-identically zero function

Tags: complex-analysis

If we consider the region $U = \{z\in\mathbb{C} : Im(z) \ne 0 \}$ and the sequence $z_n = (1+n^{-1})i$ can we find a holomorphic function that is not identically zero, but is zero at $z_n$?

Now I've answered this question before when $im(z) = 0$ wasn't excluded, in which case the answer is no by the identity theorem. However now that this problem point has been removed, I'm guessing the answer is probably yes, but I am struggling to construct such a function, any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mean analytic function, right?

Comment: The point is: $U$ is not connected.

Comment: Yes $f$ should be analytic, will add that to the post. @DanielFischer I'm not quite sure why $U$ being connected matters?

Comment: Look at the statement of the identity theorem. Does it contain the word "connected"? (It may be indirect, it may speak of a "domain", which is a "connected open set".)

Comment: So that means the identity theorem doesn't rule out the possibility of such a function, but I am still struggling to find one in that case

Comment: Actually can we use $f(z) = sin(\frac{\pi}{iz - 1})$?

Comment: I don't think $U$'s connectivity is important. (For example, throw in the negative imaginary axis - $U$ becomes connected, but the "problem" remains.) What is important is that the limit of the sequence is not in the domain of the analytic function.

Comment: @GregMartin $(1+n^{-1})i \to i\in U$.

Comment: @Wooster No, that doesn't work. As written, it doesn't vanish in all $z_n$, since $iz_n - 1 = -(1+n^{-1}) - 1 = -2 - n^{-1}$, and if you fix it by taking $iz+1$ in the denominator of the argument, the function has an essential singularity in $i$, and hence is not analytic in (all of) $U$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: ok, I was confusing the two axes. I'm on board with you now

Comment: On the issue about the domain being connected: We may replace $U$ by $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : Im(z)>0 \}$ and ask the same question. That is, use the upper half-plane; the terms of the given sequence are all in that half-plane anyway.

Comment: @coffeemath That would change the answer.

Comment: @DanielFisher Agreeed. Note that as stated one can just define $f(z)$ to be an arbitrary holomorphic below the real axis, zero above it, and undefined on the real axis.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. So $U$ is not connected, so the identity theorem tells us nothing about the existence of such a function. Is there another reason why such a function cannot exist?

Comment: Funny title, by the way…

Comment: Oh yeah, it's not great is it! I've edited it but not sure thats much better either!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $z_n = (1+n^{-1})i$ converges to $i\in U$, so the identity theorem tells us that every holomorphic function vanishing in all $z_n$ must vanish identically *on the connected component of* $U$ *that contains* $i$.

Thus an $f\in \mathscr{O}(U)$ vanishing in all $z_n$ is identically zero on the upper half-plane.

But since the upper and lower half-plane are separated by the real axis (and *all* $z_n$ lie in the upper half plane), the behaviour of $f$ on the lower half-plane is not influenced at all by the behaviour on the upper half-plane. So we can take any function $g$ holomorphic in the lower half-plane, and

$$f(z) = \begin{cases} \; 0 &, \operatorname{Im} z > 0\\ g(z) &, \operatorname{Im} z < 0\end{cases}$$

is a function holomorphic on $U$ that vanishes in all $z_n$, and $f \equiv 0$ if and only if $g \equiv 0$. Choosing $g(z) = 1$ or $g(z) = z$ (to list two simple explicit examples), we obtain a function $f\in\mathscr{O}(U)$ vanishing in all $z_n$ without being identically $0$.